# Can "east and west meet each other at some points"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

This is my sentence:

> East and west meet each other at some points and even give hugs to each other.

I am not sure if this is a correct usage of **meet** and **point** to convey the meaning, which is:

> East and west act/react the same about some special matters sometimes.

I searched for the exact sentence and didn't find it, then I tried to look in dictionaries for the word [**point**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/point):

> **3**  [countable] a particular moment in time
>   at this/that point:
>
> At that point we all got up and walked out of the room.
>      at this/that point in time:
>
> At this point in time we can't afford to hire any more people.

And:

> **4**  [countable] a particular place
>
> We'll meet at a point halfway between here and your hotel.
>
> A point where three different countries meet

Comment: What do "East" and "West" refer to in your examples?

Comment: East refers to east and west refers to west in lifestyle, science, sociology and politics, law and rules. Traditionally west mean Europe, north America and Australia and east mean Asia, Africa and south America.

Comment: What do you mean by these two cultures "giving hugs to each other"?

Comment: I think I have said it before: East and west act/react the same about some special matters sometimes. Giving hugs is more than only a simple meeting so it means they like to act/react same each other sometimes about some matters!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Whenever you speak of East and West "meeting" you are echoing a once very famous poem by Rudyard Kipling, ["The Ballad of East and West"](http://www.theotherpages.org/poems/kiplin01.html), which begins and ends

   > *OH, East is East and West is West, and never the twain shall meet,
   >
   >   Till Earth and Sky stand presently at God's great Judgement Seat;
   >
   >   But there is neither East nor West, Border, nor Breed, nor Birth,
   >
   >   When two strong men stand face to face, tho' they come from the ends of the earth!*

   Although it is unlikely that many of your readers will actually know the poem, the first line is frequently quoted and has become a generally known catchphrase. Here *meet* has just the meaning it seems you intend: to agree, to share a common outlook. We speak in the same sense of a *meeting of minds*.

   Note that you don't need the phrase *each other*—that is 'built in' to the verb.
2. *Some points* in the sense of *some matters* is idiomatic. (It's meaning #1 in the dictionary you link to.) But ***at*** some points is used of physical or temporal locations, which is not what you want. (After all, geographical East and West **do** meet at infinite points along the border which divides them!) We speak of agreeing or disagreeing ***on*** points, rather than *at* them.
3. *Give hugs to each other* has a domestic, sentimental ring which I think is in the wrong register for what you are saying. I suggest *embrace* instead—which is doubly appropriate because we speak of embracing not only people but ideas and attitudes, too.

I think what you want is something more like:

> **East and West *do* meet, and even embrace, on some points.**

Comment: My dear teacher! Thanks a lot! You solved my problem completely. I am smiling.. Ah! and about that poem.. Not only many of my readers also me myself didn't know or read it!..: ) ..

Comment: @PersianCat It's not something I'd expect learners to know, particularly learners from your part of the world. Kipling was the leading poet of British imperialism, and is not well regarded today. This poem is about Afghanistan (which like your own country was in his day the no-man's-land between the British and Russian empires), and the "two strong men" are an English soldier and an Afghan warlord.

Comment: Great! I didn't know!.. Interesting!.. : )

Answer (score 1):

I think the definition of *point* that you are using is the first one from the dictionary you linked:

> 1. [countable] an idea or opinion among a number of others.

An idiomatic way to express your meaning might be

> East and West agree and even cooperate on some points.

**Edit**

My example applies better to eastern and western governments than to the overall cultures. Cultures aren't really cohesive enough to agree or disagree on "points". "Areas" implies something less specific than points so might fit better in your context:

> East and West have overlapping values and interests in some areas.
>
> Eastern and Western values meet in some areas.

There is a common idiom, "east meets west", which doesn't necessarily imply agreement. It often is used for a cultural idiom that blends aspects of eastern and western culture (for example, a European painter exploring eastern styles, or a chef blending Asian and European cuisines).

Comment: But it is not the answer. I asked to find whether my sentence is correct to use to convey this meaning or not. If not so I could use it instead of the first sentence which I am searching to find for its correctness. And cooperation is not the meaning that I want to convey it.

Comment: Your example sentence, "East and west meet each other at some points and even give hugs to each other", is not fluent. I suggested an alternate, more idiomatic, statement based on my limited understanding of what you were trying to convey.